# I am trying to train my network on iris data but having the following error. Although I changed the type as well, but it still pops up the same error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

```
'num_epochs = 500
train_loss = []
test_loss = []
train_accuracy = []
test_accuracy = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    train_correct = 0
    train_total = 0

    for i, (items, classes) in enumerate(train_loader):
    
        items = Variable(items)
        classes = Variable(classes)
    
        net. train()           # Put the network into training mode
    
        optimizer.zero_grad() # Clear off the gradients from any past operation
        outputs = net(items)  # Do the forward pass
        loss = criterion(outputs, classes) # Calculate the loss
        loss.backward()       # Calculate the gradients with help of back propagation
        optimizer.step()      # Ask the optimizer to adjust the parameters based on the gradients
    
        train_total += classes.size(0)    
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        train_correct += (predicted == classes.data).sum()

        print ('Epoch %d/%d, Iteration %d/%d, Loss: %.4f' 
           %(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, len(train_ds)//batch_size, loss.data[0]))

    net.eval()                 # Put the network into evaluation mode

    train_loss.append(loss.data[0])

    train_accuracy.append((100 * train_correct / train_total))

    
    test_items = torch.FloatTensor(test_ds.data.values[:, 0:4])
    test_classes = torch.LongTensor(test_ds.data.values[:, 4])

    outputs = net(Variable(test_items))
    loss = criterion(outputs, Variable(test_classes))
    test_loss.append(loss.data[0])
    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
    total = test_classes.size(0)
    correct = (predicted == test_classes).sum()
    test_accuracy.append((100 * correct / total))`'
```

And the error I get is

```
RuntimeError                              
       Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-21-d25f2c091906> in <module>
        21         optimizer.zero_grad() # Clear off the gradients from any past operation
        22         outputs = net(items)  # Do the forward pass
        ---> 23         loss = criterion(outputs, classes) # Calculate the loss
        24         loss.backward()       # Calculate the gradients with help of back propagation
        25         optimizer.step()      # Ask the optimizer to adjust the parameters based on the gradients

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Int
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems it is this line `loss = criterion(outputs, classes)` generating the error.

Change `classes = Variable(classes)` to `classes = Variable(classes).long()` to convert `classes` to type `Long` has the `criterion` method expects.

Comment: I did the same and it gives the error: IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use `tensor.item()` in Python or `tensor.item<T>()` in C++ to convert a 0-dim tensor to a number

Comment: Using `loss.data[0]` is deprecated and it is advised to use `loss.item()`. Changing every where you have `loss.data[0]` to `loss.item()` should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, sir, but the problem is with Type have a look at runtime error above. If you have a clue about it I would be thankful

Comment: I already answered that in my post. The comment is a **continuation** of my post and it addresses the `IndexError` you wrote about in the comment.